# Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement. Multiple "if" in iReport expression if (cond) then expr1 else expr2 endif

Tags: groovy, crystal-reports, jasper-reports, ireport

I have to convert some reports from Crystal to Jasper and Groovy gives me headaches. I have an expression with multiple "if":

```
if (cond) then expr1 else expr2 endif.
```

In iReport this comes `(cond) ? expr1 : expr2`, but if i have another if condition and i place it under the first one i get erors. Could you give me some advice? Thank you!

Expression to convert:

```
if not isnull({ZEM0000_T.PRUEFMERKMAL}) then
        text = {ZEM0000_T.PRUEFMERKMAL}
else
        text = ""
end if

if not isnull ({ZEM0000_T.ANWEISUNG1}) then
        text = text & Chr(13) & trim({ZEM0000_T.ANWEISUNG1})
end if

if not isnull ({ZEM0000_T.ANWEISUNG2}) then
        text = text & Chr(13) & trim({ZEM0000_T.ANWEISUNG2})
end if

if not isnull ({ZEM0000_T.ANWEISUNG3}) then
        text = text & Chr(13) & trim({ZEM0000_T.ANWEISUNG3})
end if

if not isnull ({@OT_NM_UT_2}) then
        text = text & Chr(13) & {@OT_NM_UT_2}
end if

formula = text
```

Comment: Do you have an example that's causing the error?

Comment: text = ($F{PRUEFMERKMAL} != null) ? $F{PRUEFMERKMAL} : ""
text = ($F{ANWEISUNG1} != null) ? text + chr(13) + trim($F{ANWEISUNG1}) : text

Comment: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement. I tried to insert ";" but no succes.

Comment: Are you putting that all on one line?

Comment: no. each if with his own line

Comment: Maybe if you put this in the question, it might help someone see what you've tried?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this code? Is it in a `textFieldExpression`?

Comment: yes, in a textFieldExpression.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in JasperReports are limited to a single expression (i.e. a single statement in Java/Groovy). They cannot be given a long script of code to execute. Your expression from Crystal Reports contains many statements, so converting the code to Groovy won't be enough, you will also have to refactor it to be one statement.

Luckily, as you are concatenating strings, you can just use the `+` operator to join each statement. So the code from your comment

```
text = ($F{PRUEFMERKMAL} != null) ? $F{PRUEFMERKMAL} : "" 
text = ($F{ANWEISUNG1} != null) ? text + chr(13) + trim($F{ANWEISUNG1}) : text
```

would need to look something like this:

```
(($F{PRUEFMERKMAL} != null) ? $F{PRUEFMERKMAL} : "") +
(($F{ANWEISUNG1} != null) ? text + chr(13) + trim($F{ANWEISUNG1}) : "")
```